XTerm JS: allowing user input/making commands (in html/js)
Ive been checking out a few HTML/JS/CSS terminals I could use for my site and I came across XTerm.js. I decided to try it out, but I'm a little confused, after plugging in some code I found from a site (forgot the name), I had the terminal loaded, but my main problem is: I don't know how to add commands, or have user input in general. I added a snippet of the terminal below, and if you try to type in it, nothing will happen, no keys are being registered.
I tried taking a look at a few questions here/sites, but none seem to help me, my knowledge is pretty low though when it comes to JS and HTML so it could also be that. I also checked the XTerm docs, but to be honest, it's a little confusing for me. Could somebody please help me out here? Id like to know how to make commands for the terminal, and allow user input.
(Also, im pretty sure I need a backend service to create "commands" for XTerm, but i am looking for something locally. Like local echo, and to run JS on a command execution.)
Here is my current code right now:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>XTerm terminalr</title>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/xterm/css/xterm.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/xterm@4.11.0/lib/xterm.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
 <div id="terminal"></div>
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/meslo@1.0.0/meslo.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
<style>

#terminal {
 width: 37%;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: meslo;
}

</style>

<script>
 
const term = new Terminal();
const shellprompt = 'root@XTerm:~# ';

function termKeyPress(ev) {
  term.on('key', (key, ev) => {
        console.log(key.charCodeAt(0));
        if (key.charCodeAt(0) == 13)
            term.write('\n');
        term.write(key);
});
}

term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'));
term.prompt = function () {
  term.write('\r' + shellprompt);
};

term.writeln('AT: localHost\n');
term.prompt();

 </script>
</body>
</html>




You never call termKeyPress function.

The onData event contains user input readily processed for a consuming PTY. You should not use the low level onKey event yourself unless you need to customize key input in awkward ways. Also you should use a much newer lib version, 4.11 is really old.

It seems you need to use onKey event. You can find it in library source code. The only documentation I was able to find was autogenerated, see onKey on the official website.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>XTerm terminalr</title>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/xterm/css/xterm.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/xterm@4.11.0/lib/xterm.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
 <div id="terminal"></div>
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/meslo@1.0.0/meslo.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
<style>

#terminal {
 width: 37%;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: meslo;
}

</style>

<script>
 
const term = new Terminal();
const shellprompt = 'root@XTerm:~# ';


term.onKey(({key, domEvent}) => {
    console.log(key.charCodeAt(0));
    if (key.charCodeAt(0) == 13) {
        term.write('\n');
    }
    term.write(key);
});

term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'));
term.prompt = function () {
  term.write('\r' + shellprompt);
};

term.writeln('AT: localHost\n');
term.prompt();

 </script>
</body>
</html>



